# How to center a frame on a canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout, customtkinter

type here

I have been working on a quiz system for my class 12 school project using [customtkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) for GUI.
on creating a scrollable frame on canvas the frame is sticking to the bottom right side and not centering
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7N2U.png)

sample code

```
    from customtkinter import *
    import tkinter

    center_frame = CTk()
    mainframe = CTkFrame(master=center_frame)
    mainframe.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

    mycanvas = CTkCanvas(mainframe)
    mycanvas.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
    mycanvas.configure(bg="#292929", highlightthickness=0)

    myscrollbar = CTkScrollbar(mainframe, orientation=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=mycanvas.yview)
    myscrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
    mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
    mycanvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")),)
    secondframe = CTkFrame(mycanvas)
    x0 = center_frame.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
    y0 = secondframe.winfo_screenheight() / 2

    mycanvas.create_window((x0, y0), window=secondframe, anchor="n")


    center_frame.mainloop()
```

this is my main project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri02Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUGev.png)

```
x0 = center_frame.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
y0 = secondframe.winfo_screenheight() / 2
```

using this piece of code i was expecting to center the frame as told by another post on this website
but all it did was change the position of the frame from this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPmyS.png)

to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVExU.png)

Comment: I don't understand why you use `x0 = center_frame.winfo_screenwidth() / 2` and `y0 = secondframe.winfo_screenheight() / 2` if you want to center `secondframe` inside `mycanvas`.  Should `x0 = mycanvas.winfo_width() / 2` and `y0 = mycanvas.winfo_height() / 2` be used instead?

Comment: @acw1668 the dimensions of the frames are the same. i have tried it it gives the same result. i have tried it with all the 4 frames which are placed on the middle frame. they all give the same result.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say in your last comment.

Comment: so basically the frames under the canvas are of the same length and width, so as you suggested using 'x0 = mycanvas.winfo_width() / 2' and 'y0 = mycanvas.winfo_height() / 2' i tried it with all of them and they all gave the same bottom right position for the scrollable frame on top of the canvas

Comment: It may be caused by using `anchor="n"` in `.create_window()`.  Try using `anchor="c"` instead.

Comment: have tried it dosent work. i have tried anchor = CENTER,tkinter.CENTER, "c". none of these work